# How long does an iAd banner have to be on the screen to successfully make an impression

Tags: ios, iad

I'm going to be using iAds in my app and I hoped to put it inside a scroll view so the user sees one only occasionally without having a clunky banner. However, I recently read that an ad has to be on the screen for a certain amount of time to make an impression. Does anyone know how long it has to be on the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: Good impression or bad impression?

Comment: @HotLicks - *chuckles* Not quite sure if you're making a joke or not. Read up on what I'm saying here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impression_(online_media)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it a small banner like 320x50 you can show it somewhere all the times (usually bottom or top).

If it is a full-screen banner, I recommend showing it not more often than 30 seconds.

Also, if it is a game, maker sure you only display it in specific states, otherwise the users will get annoyed and write bad reviews.

Comment: Thanks. What about interstitial ads?

Comment: Basically, the same thing as for full-screen ads applies in this case. Just make sure you do not show them too often.

Comment: Thanks. I really hate ads myself, and I was just trying to not make them get in the way of my app (by making them work inline, and not as a banner), but oh well. I guess I'm stuck with that.